# Mariadb insert error code 4025 Constraint fail problem

Tags: mariadb, constraints

I am trying to input the following MySQL query

```
INSERT INTO `shoppingcentre_ga` (`CentreCode`, `CentreName`, `Location`) VALUES ('Test', 'Enoch', 'Downtown')
```

but i keep getting the following error code

> 4025 - CONSTRAINT `CHK_CentreCode` failed for `shopping_centres`.`shoppingcentre_ga`

I am a beginner and any help is much appreciated

Comment: Sounds like the `CenterCode` value `Test` is not a valid entry. Check that table to see what the other entry values are for `CenterCode`.  Hint: CenterCODE, to me, sounds like a number, not text.

Comment: @PaulT.i tried using numbers but i get the same error code

Comment: Without knowing the table definition, that was only a guess. Run this SQL and append the output to the question, NOT in a comment:  `SHOW CREATE TABLE shoppingcentre_ga;`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem because i was inserting "*bad data in one of my columns*".

If you can **show** us the **structure** of your **table** + the **type of data** you want to insert, it might help us a bit more.

To come back to the resolution of my problem, I was trying to insert `text` in a column typed by `json`. What could not work haha ^^ (head in the handlebar)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Without the SQL command of your `shopping-center` table, it is impossible to guide you. Basically this is the order that you suppose to pass when inserting data in a MariaDB table.
1- I wish you use [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/download.php) which is working fine with MariaDB.
2- Create the [table](https://www.heidisql.com/screenshots.php?which=table_editor)
3- if you want to test, initially, do not set any primary-key and foreign-key.
4- then insert the data.

Note: if you have primary-key well set, in first insert should not leave it blank, just give a value (like 1 , 25, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table should accept that query,
try checking the Collation. I faced a similar problem only to realize that the Collation for my data column had changed and changing it back to `utf8mb4_general_ci` solved the problem for me.